# How do I block commit in Eclipse if there are special TODO tags in code?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Can Eclipse warn or prevent Git commits if there are special tags in the code?

These would not necessarily be  `TODO` tags, but rather something like `DEVONLY` to indicate logging or instrumentation that was inserted temporarily for development, and which should not go to the shared repository.

Intellij supports this.

How can this be done in Eclipse?

Comment: What if the dev-code is commented, but the tag is still there?

Comment: You can prohibit committing if there are warnings in the code, and you can configure to show warnings for various things, but on first glance, I did not find an option for those task-tags.